# Magento global attributes not saving globally

Tags: magento

I have a few attributes that we've added to catalog/product, with global scope set, but when a value for that attribute is set at a store level, that value is applying only to that store.  E.G. I set stock_status (see below) to out of stock on store 1, but after saving, the stock_status on store 2 is still in stock.

I have also set the price attribute to global in System/Configuration/Catalog/Price, and I'm having the same problem there, where setting the price in either the default store view, or one of the individual store views only applies that that specific store.  SKU appears to be the only globally scoped attribute that is working as expected.

Here's the upgrade script for one of the attributes:

```
$installer->installEntities(
array(
    'catalog_product' => array(
            'entity_model'      => 'catalog/product',
            'attribute_model'   => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
            'table'             => 'catalog/product',
            'attributes'        => array(
                'stock_status' => array(
                    'type'              => 'int',
                    'backend'           => '',
                    'label'             => 'Stock Status',
                    'input'             => 'select',
                    'source'            => 'catalog/product_attribute_source_stockStatus',
                    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible'           => true,
                    'required'          => false,
                    'user_defined'      => false,
                    'default'           => '0',
                    'searchable'        => true,
                    'filterable'        => true,
                    'comparable'        => true,
                    'visible_on_front'  => false,
                    'unique'            => false,
                )))));
```

We are unfortunately using an older version of Magento (1.1.8), and have no opportunity to upgrade at this point.